# Input handling completely breaks when more than a single key is held at once

Tags: java, arrays, input, libgdx

I have some suspicions about the way I'm handling the `heldKeys` variable (adding and removing `keycodes` from it).

Everything works fine when only a single key is pressed at once (and this is why I believe the problem, but be in the this class, and not the ones that take care of drawing or updating). However, everything completely breaks when I press more than one key at the same time.

By "breaks", it no longer works properly: pressing up moves all subscribers up sometimes, other times moves the one that should move up up, and the others down, etc. Other times a certain action stops doing anything until I restart the program.

I've tried debugging and seeing the evolution of the `heldKeys` array, but I really have no clue where the problem is.

#### Code:

```
<code>

    public class MainInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {


    // REFERENCE:
    // <Listener, <ACTION, KEYCODE>>
    private Array<ObjectMap<RacketMovementListener, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer>>> racketMovementListeners;

    // Stores the keys that are held down
    private IntArray heldKeys;


    // Initialisation
    public MainInputProcessor() {
        heldKeys = new IntArray();
        racketMovementListeners = new Array<ObjectMap<RacketMovementListener, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer>>>();

    }

    // Adds a RacketMovementListener to the respective subscriber list
    public void subscribeToRacketMovement(RacketMovementListener newSubscriber, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer> movementKeys) {
        ObjectMap<RacketMovementListener, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer>> map = new ObjectMap<RacketMovementListener, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer>>();

        map.put(newSubscriber, movementKeys);

        racketMovementListeners.add(map);
    }

    // Update and execute event action
    public void updateEvents() {

        // Fire events for racket movement subscribers if the keys match
        if (!heldKeys.isEmpty()) {
            for (ObjectMap<RacketMovementListener, ObjectMap<Racket.ACTIONS, Integer>> map : racketMovementListeners) {
                for (RacketMovementListener listener : map.keys()) {
                    for (Integer keycode : heldKeys.items) {

                        if (map.get(listener).get(Racket.ACTIONS.MOVE_DOWN).equals(keycode)) {
                            listener.moveDownPressed(listener);
                        } if (map.get(listener).get(Racket.ACTIONS.MOVE_UP).equals(keycode)) {
                            listener.moveUpPressed(listener);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        // Add keycode to heldKeys if it's not already there
        if (!heldKeys.contains(keycode)) {
            heldKeys.add(keycode);
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // Remove keycode from heldKeys since the key is no longer held down
        for (Integer code : heldKeys.items) {
            if (code == keycode) {
                heldKeys.removeValue(code);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
</code>
```

I'm not really looking for solutions or fixed code, just some starting point or somewhere to look, because I don't even know where to start. I've thought about rewriting this but I think I would do the same mistakes.

For context, this is code for a Pong clone, in LibGDX.

**UPDATE**

I rewrote the whole input manager to do the exact same but using switch statements and overall in a simpler way, but the exact same problem remains.

I'm now sure the problem is in the way I'm handling the `heldKeys` array.
However, I still can't figure out the problem with it...

Comment: What happens in your heldKeys array when you press or release more than one key?

Comment: @LuisFernandoFrontanilla When I press more than one key,  both keys get added to the array. However, after a bit of debugging, I discovered that when I released those 2 keys only one got removed from the array, so it's like the key was still held down... I still couldn't figure out how to fix it since clearing the array didn't work for some reason?

Comment: I know this is could be a bad workaround but you could try using some booleans for tracking what is pressed and what not for now, until someone answers here or you come up with a solution

Comment: That's not a bad workaround,  that's the way you must go. Use boolean values for example: `moveUp = false;`. If user press W set this to true and somewhere else you can check `if(moveUp) applyForce to player` and if the player releases the key set moveUp to false. It's easier to handle and faster than always search in the array for the key which is now released.